# SQL Server 2008: Bulk Insert taking forever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a txt file(tab delimited) which has almost 1200 records. I m doing a bulk insert operation to get the data from .txt file to a table- which(structure) is already created in the database.
I don't know why bulk insert is taking forever. Any suggestions on where/what/how to check what's causing this operation to take forever? Thanks. I did it before as well and it used to work fine. Any reasons?

```
BULK INSERT DataFromatltemp
 FROM '\\abcd\Admin\temp\Copyatltemp07.txt'
 WITH
 (
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
 )
GO
```

Comment: Are there any opened transactions that work on this table?

Comment: Check for blocking spids. You might have a long running query blocking your inserts.

Comment: No this table is untouched and I created it for my use only. Thanks.

Comment: Define forever :)? Maybe your database have to grow it's database file due the fact the grow size is set to 1MB. Check DB options, file groups and grow parameters of file and log file.

Comment: can you put the DB in single user mode and run the insert. If it runs fast (or at least, not forever) it is a blocking issue, so you would need to analyse what other process may be impacting on the inserts you are running against the DB. I would also advise to put the text file on a local share, maybe the remote path is causing some delay

Comment: I used the term 'Forever' because it was running/executing w/o fetching the results. I stopped execution.

Comment: I just happend to have resolved something similar. Are both machines member of the same DOMAIN? Is the SQL Server Engine Service running with a domain user? Have you tried to do the same thing using the file on a SQL Server local file?

Answer (score -1):

As almost everything related to RDBMS and performance, it depends on a series of variables, but there are some hints you can look first:

1. database: assure your database is using simple recovery mode;
2. target table: clear all constraints (including checks, foreign keys);
3. target table: drop all indexes;
4. target table: assure is's not locked by any other process;
5. source file: assure is's not locked by any other process;

I hope this hints can be helpful.

Comment: Single recovery mode? Clear constraints and drop indexes? why would you drop all indexes to perform a bulk insert?

Comment: @Diego, my suggestion in using "Simple Recovery Mode" was meant not to log bulk operations (that can lead to unnecessary disk overhead). The reason to drop indexes and foreign keys on target table was also to avoid disk overhead. Maybe my suggestions do not suffice to solve Nemo's problem, but you should reconsider calling them wrong.

Comment: it is wrong. Single recovery model should never be used on a production environment. Clear all constraints and drop all indexes is a terrible advise. how about the data integrity while the insert is being done? Not mentioning the time necessary to drop and recreate the indexes?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. I found the answer. 
I created DataFromatltemp table using syntax SELECT * INTO tblNew FROM tblOld WHERE 1=2
which means I copied the structure of my table from an existing table. Then I dropped the old table,
however the new table which is  'DataFromatltemp' has some refs to the old deleted one(may be ?). When I deleted 'DataFromatltemp' and recreated it with a different name, then ran bulk insert operation, it worked fine. Fetched my 1192 records withing 2 secs. 
Thanks again for your time. I learned something new from your discussion. :)

Comment: @Diego, are you implying that tables in an ETL *staging* database should have foreign keys and indexes? It should be common sense, but if you need another opinion, take msdn: "A best practice ... is to disable foreign key constraints in the data mart and to rely on the ETL for managing consistency during the load process." [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671624.aspx]

Comment: @Nemo nice you found the error and even better you could have more insight on the theme :)

Comment: he never mentioned staging tables or SPECIALLY data mart. As far as we are concern he's dealing with a regular OLTP database where, again, disabling index, constraints and specially single recovery mode are very bad advises. On a data warehouse scenario is another story, if you have a consistent ETL process, yes, I would agree on removing the FKs but on his scenario, no.

Comment: @Diego There's no context given, and there are many environments where the above recommendations are perfectly valid and can lead to significant performance gains.