# SQL server 2008: Copy a file and rename it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a file inside a directory `\\myServer\Admin\temp\testtemp.txt`

I need to write a TSQL to

1. Search for `testtemp.txt` file.
2. If exists, create a copy of it and rename it to `Copytesttemp.txt`
3. If there's `testtemp.txt` already in the above directory like this

   ```
   \\abcd\Admin\temp\Copytesttemp.txt
   ```
4. then delete it and recreate `Copytesttemp.txt`

How do I achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: this is a small fraction of my TSQL. I want to be able to pass this new copytesttemp.txt file to my bulk insert operation and later query the table resulted from bulk insert, create a view etc etc.

Comment: What have you tried - we don't just step by step do everything we can only provide guidance.

Comment: In ref to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486013/sql-server-2008-bulk-insert-taking-forever , I need to be able to pass Copytesttemp.txt file to my Bulk Insert operation.Please let me know if you need further explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use xp_cmdshell to run any DOS commands you like, e.g.

```
declare @cmdstring varchar(1000)

set @cmdstring = 'copy \\myServer\Admin\temp\testtemp.txt \\myServer\Admin\temp\Copytesttemp.txt'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstring
```

Just make sure xp_cmdshell is enabled on your installation.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your help. But I get access denied, 0 file(s) copied. I checked and found that xp_cmdshell is installed/enabled on my server. Any clue?

Comment: Check out what account SQL Server is running as and then check that account is able to Read/Write the shared directory you're trying to write to.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It was permission issue and it got fixed. I was given permission to access resources in the network.

Answer (score 2):

Create a SQL Agent job which runs a command script to do the actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for Copy a file and rename

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'COPY D:\T1\a.txt D:\T2\b.txt'
```

Only copy and move just like CMD

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'COPY D:\T1\abcd.txt D:\T2'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'Move D:\T1\abcd.txt D:\T2'
```